# Write operation in Reverse Relationship Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='car/')
```

For the serializer I have:

```
class CarImageSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CarImage

class CarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    photos = CarImageSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos',)
```

When the web interface for `CarSerializer` loads I get `non_field_errors` on the `photos` field by default. Is this kind of thing supported by DRF? If not what's the best way to do this?
P.S I am using generic `CreateAPIView`

Comment: If you find/found an answer let me know I'm about to post a similar question.  Again trying to POST to a model linked by reverse relationship.

Comment: Haven't found answer yet!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `CreateAPIView`? It can only create new entry per `post`. If you want also to display the entries per `get` you should take `ListCreateAPIView`?

Comment: You have a bad typo in your serializer classes: `serializer.ModelSerializer`. It must be `serializers.ModelSerializer`. You have certainly this: `from rest_framework import serializers`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations) you should do this from another way:

```
class CarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    photos = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos',)
```

Comment: I can't see the photos field on the web interface, if I do this. Also, is reverse relation insert handled by generic API View?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

**serializers.py**

```
class CarImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CarImage


class CarSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    photos = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                                 view_name='carimage-list')

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos',)
```

**views.py**

```
class CarImageList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = CarImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarImageSerializer


class CarList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^carimage/$', CarImageList.as_view(), name='carimage-list'),
url(r'^car/$', CarList.as_view(), name='car-list'),
```

You should take care about all needed imports. No guarantee, but you could give it a try.